# kik OpenUrl video link iOS

Tags: ios, kik

In my app I have been able to share a video link to send to Facebook Messenger using:

```
 string facebookMessengerUrl = "fb-messenger://share?link=" +
 uriToShare;
 NSUrl facebookUrl = new NSUrl(facebookMessengerUrl);
 if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(facebookUrl))
 {
      UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(facebookUrl);
 }
```

Of course, I have also added the following entry "fb-messenger" in "Info.plist", under "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes".

I have added a similar functionality for WhatsApp, Line and Messenger sucessfully; however I cannot send properly the video to the Kik app. The following code opens the Kik app but then I got an "unexpected error" and the video or its url is not shown and I cannot send it to any user.

```
 string kikStr = "kik-share://kik.com/send/video&video_url=" +
 uriToShare;
 NSUrl kikUrl = new NSUrl(kikStr);
 if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(kikUrl))
 {
      UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(kikUrl);
 }
```

Of course, I have also added "kid-share", in Info.plist, in the section LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

I have tried several variants of the scheme:

```
"kik-share://kik.com/send/video&video_url="
```

but without any right result.

The code is C sharp but do not pay attention on this detail (the same wrong result happens using Swift), the main goal is to know the suitable scheme to use; that is:

```
"kik-share://I_do_not_know"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to send a URL link; this is the way I have done:

```
 string title = "MyTitle";
 string appName = "MyAppName";
 string appPkg = "com.my.bundle.id";
 string referer = "com.my.bundle.id";
 string uriToShare = "www.google.com"; // For example
 string kikStr = "kik-share://kik.com/send/article?app_name=" + appName +
                 "&app_pkg=" + appPkg +
                 "&icon_url=data%3Aimage%2Fjpg%3Bbase64%2C%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD%2F4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAAIKADAAQAAAABAAAAIAAAAAD%2F7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs%2BEJ%2B%2F8AAEQgAIAAgAwEiAAIRAQMRAf%2FEAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC%2F%2FEALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29%2Fj5%2Bv%2FEAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC%2F%2FEALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5%2Bjp6vLz9PX29%2Fj5%2Bv%2FbAEMABAQEBAQEBgQEBgkGBgYJDAkJCQkMDwwMDAwMDxIPDw8PDw8SEhISEhISEhUVFRUVFRkZGRkZHBwcHBwcHBwcHP%2FbAEMBBAUFBwcHDAcHDB0UEBQdHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHR0dHf%2FdAAQAAv%2FaAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A%2BbUV5W2RqWPoKm%2By3X%2FPM%2FpV3w1pra9qtpoiSCI6hdQW%2B8gkKJGIycc4r0SX4RyfZJNTh1eD7LIUNrlCHdZA%2BNyuylSChGBuz1HFVKpGLszM8u%2By3X%2FPM%2FpUDh422SKVYdjXsWu%2FBe90NJby71KCK0tzJvYI8jtFEq%2FvkReWDs21V4xyScCvL%2FEelXHh%2FUX0a6dZJbVmXemcMpwykA4IyGBwRkdDzThJSV0Fz%2F%2FQ%2BYtPv7iymW5s5jBcwuksUittKshyCG7EdRXSN448atJKDqtyzXIJkPnMd4wVG47sYUZC56VwO6pWuZGjWInCKMYHfvz69auUIy1aMrI7X%2FhMfF4dJV1aYSREFHFx8ynBUkHdxuBIPrmudvrye6l866ma4uHLPLIzF2ZnOSSxzk%2BprH3UbqcYqKtFDsf%2F2Q%3D%3D" +
                 "&native=0" +
                 "&referer=" + referer +
                 "&forwardable=1&disallow_save=0&url=" + uriToShare +
                 "&title=" + title;
```

So, if I replace the kikStr in the aforementioned code I can share the URL in Kik.